# How to handle disconnect in grpc bidirect stream?

Tags: c++, grpc

I have bidirect async stream using gprc and unable to find how to subscribe to disconnect event(both cases : closed by server or network problem). In grpc documentation 
https://grpc.github.io/grpc/cpp/classgrpc_1_1_client_async_reader_writer_interface.html
I only see function WritesDone (void *tag) that initiate closing and signal that finished. But there are no way for subscribe on event on disconnect by another reason.